# Exp:resso Store - Checkout listing and Matrix Images - bug?

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, matrix

In the Expresso Store channel, my images are in a Matrix array, and while I can see it on the product page, the first checkout page ignores the matrix wrapping fields:

```
 {store_preview limit="1"}
    <img src="{img}">
 {/store_preview}
```

which generates this on the checkout listing:

```
{store_preview limit="1"} (broken image graphic) {/store_preview}
```

(this also gets pushed through CE Image, so I need to wrap the entire  element). It appears it's being parsed as text - so no image gets called. Bah.

Has anyone seen this? Could this a bug the `{exp:store:checkout}` pair, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a channel entries tag to get custom fields to show up on in the cart, checkout, & order tags. Something along the lines of:

```
{exp:store:checkout}
 {items}
  {exp:channel:entries limit="1" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
   {store_preview limit="1"}
    <img src="{img}">
   {/store_preview}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
 {/items}
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

Basic things such as the Title, Entry ID, URL Title, and store related tags do not need the channel entries tags to be shown though.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to wrap entries with the checkout pair - somehow it seems counterintuitive, pair in pair, but it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh yea some tags like the `{exp:store:search}` tag are basically wrappers for the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag so you don't need to nest the channels tag within. This does add some overhead though which would be my assumption why the cart, checkout, and order tags do not allow this. Personally I think it would be great if there was an additional parameter like `channel_tag="yes/no"` that could be added to allow you to parse fields in the `exp_channel_data` table on a case by case basis for each tag.

Comment: Based on provided answer my code looks like `{exp:store:checkout form_class="form-horizontal"}{items}Pass 1{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}Pass 2{product_image limit="1"}{product_image:image}{/product_image}{/exp:channel:entries}{/items}{/exp:store:checkout}` but Pass 2 is not getting displayed. Any clue?

Comment: It is probably best to start a new question and provide a link in the comments

Comment: Perhaps retype that closing {/checkout} tag - I'm seeing a odd character in Chrome right after the "{/e".